# How to ssh to remote in script without having to provide a password

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am executing the following in my script:
`ssh pi@192.169.1.89`

Which asks me for a password
`pi@192.169.1.89's password:`

How do I execute the script to create the ssh connection and then pass the password into it, so I don't have to type it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is `ssh keys`, then you wont have to type a `password`.

To generate RSA keys, on the command line, enter:

```
ssh-keygen -o -b 4096 -t rsa
```

NOTE THIS:
If you don't password-protect your private key, anyone with access to your computer conceivably can SSH (without being prompted for a password) to your account on any remote system that has the corresponding public key.

Your private key will be generated using the default filename (for example, `id_rsa`) or the filename you specified (for example, my_ssh_key), and stored on your computer in a .ssh directory off your home directory (for example, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/my_ssh_key`).

If your account on the remote system doesn't already contain a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, create one; on the command line, enter the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

To copy your key to the remote server:

`ssh-copy-id` is a utility available on some operating systems that can copy a `SSH` public key to a remote server over `SSH`.

To use `ssh-copy-id`, pass your username and the IP address of the server you would like to access:

```
ssh-copy-id USER@IP-ADDRESS
```

ref:

[Use Public Key Authentication with SSH](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/)

[Set up SSH public-key authentication to connect to a remote system](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but I recommend using public/private keys rather than passing the password (which is possible). There are many other answers on this - but here is a quick how to:

On the machine you are logging in from:

Create a public/private key combination:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Copy the public key to the remote machine:

`ssh-copy-id pi@192.168.1.89`

You will then need to type your password, and the public key will be copied to 192.168.1.89. At this point you will no longer be asked for your password upon logging in from the first machine.